# Conditional Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a collection of checkboxes that are created on the fly based on information from a database. If any of the checkboxes are checked, a corresponding div opens up containing textboxes which can be filled in. I need to then record the information from only the textboxes which have corresponding checkboxes that are checked. How would I go about binding only the information that has a parent checkbox checked? BTW: All of the information is part of a larger complex object.

Comment: After each divs text boxes are filled in can you simply send those off via a json post to the server to save?

Comment: Nope. Each div is part of a larger complex object, and I wont save the data until the user hits save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditionally binding like this isn't really feasible.  Instead do this:

Create a different set of properties or create an object for each section, then when the form is posted to the server check the values of the check boxes and pull the necessary data from the appropriate fields, ignoring the others.

For example, lets say you have two sections, one with a "Name" field, and the other with an "Address" field.  Check to see if the Name checkbox is checked, and if it is, get the value of "Name", otherwise ignore it.

Comment: So instead of one large complex object, I would bind to a list of each checkbox's model then determine what to do with the model based on a controller Request[] of the checkbox status? Is this the correct thinking?

Comment: You wouldn't need to use a list, unless you are expecting a variable number of sections.  For my example, you could create a "Name" object and an "Address" object.  Then add those to your view model, and for each section render fields on those objects.

Comment: Oh. Yes. Each section is created dynamically based on what is pulled back from the database. So there could be one to many checkboxes, each with a copy of the same subdivision.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the necessary data from the appropriate fields"? Are you talking about using `Request.Form["Name"]`?